# SQL Join Issue return DISTINCT Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, join

I have the following two tables with data like so:

```
Table Values
 var_label
 1
 2
 2
 1
 3

Table Codes
var_code
1
2
4
2
```

I need to join these tables and get the distinct result.  The var_label and var_code are equal pieces of data.  I want to have the joined output like so:

```
 MyColumn
1
2
3
4
```

Wht's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION` without `ALL`(implicit distinct) like so:

```
SELECT var_label AS MyColumn
FROM Values
UNION
SELECT var_code
FROM Codes
```

### [Live Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/83318/sql-join-issue-return-distinct-names)

Comment: oh yeah duh forgot about that

Comment: will this create var_label and var_data as column names

Comment: @chris Add the alais name in the first `SELECT` like in my edit.

Comment: i think second query also need the same name?

Comment: @ArunKillu It will take the name of the column from the first `SELECT` to be the alias of the result set.

Comment: @ArunKillu No it doesn't. Try it

Comment: ok so i will delete my answer..10x @MahmoudGamal for that info

Comment: @ArunKillu You can leave your answer it is not wrong. It is helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT var_label
FROM Table1 as MyColumn
UNION
SELECT var_data as MyColumn
FROM Table2
```

you can give aliases for getting only one colum name.

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76d8d/4)**

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct(var_label)
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT distinct(var_data)
FROM Table2

Comment: not really...it works without distinct. however, it works with distinct as well http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76d8d/7